# downloading large zip files to the browser in php, chunking

Tags: php, chunking

I am trying to download large zip files (800MB to 1GB) containing audio files to the browser. As I have seen so far, chunking seems to be the most popular approach, but I am having zero luck. The code I have been working with is

```
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filepath;
$download_rate = 5000;
$progress = 0;

if (file_exists($filename)) {

    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename='.basename($filename));

    flush();
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    while(!feof($file)) {
        // send the current file part to the browser
        print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));
        // flush the content to the browser
        flush();
        // sleep one second
        sleep(1);
    }
    fclose($file);

} else echo 'File does not exist!';
```

This works for a wide variety of file types and sizes up to a certain point -- I have no problem downloading typical PDFs, etc. But the browser just spins and spins when I try to download large zip files, and eventually dies (around 2 minutes). I am really needing some help here. I've tried a number of code variants for chucking, but something always seems to die and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Perhaps there's a better approach to chunking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not enough chunks in my chunksize - PHP download script result in 20% file size download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371528/not-enough-chunks-in-my-chunksize-php-download-script-result-in-20-file-size) The suggestion there is to use a library that already handles this sort of logic (CURL).

Answer (score 0):

Consider change change for readfile will not present any memory issues, your lost download rate and progress show in browser. your limit download rate in .httaccess.

```
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $filepath;

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename));
    readfile($filename);

} else echo 'File does not exist!';
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php